# Accessing an Objective-C sharedInstance in a Swift app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, singleton

I'm writing an app in Swift that relies on an Obj-C library, FRDStravaClient which needs to be a sharedInstance. What's the best way instantiate the sharedInstance and use it throughout my app?

```
@implementation FRDStravaClient

+(FRDStravaClient *) sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id instance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}
```

For the sake of moving forward I've defined a struct so I have a global var that refers to my instance. But all I read talks about how global vars are an abomination

```
struct EvilGlobalVars {
    static var stravaClient = FRDStravaClient()
    static var authToken = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("authToken")
}
```

Comment: Does it even matter ? As long as you can access objective c class from swift, can't you access it directly using FRDStravaClient.sharedInstance()

Comment: Use `let` instead of `var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've created a `sharedInstance` as above, you can just access it as `FRDStravaClient.sharedInstance()` anywhere you want it in Swift. You don't need a global struct.